# How do I save multiple entries from multiple Entry widgets in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Before anyone marks it as a duplicate question, please read ahead.

I have ***multiple*** entry widgets where the user enters `DoubleVar()` inputs. Each entry box has its own Label that has been manually labelled.

I have successfully managed to capture the entry value of ***one*** box by creating the following function and creating a `button` that calls this function -

```
def get_entry():
    EntryValue=EntryBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(EntryValue)
```

Is there a way to apply the same logic for ***multiple*** entry boxes **WITH** the label of the EntryBox and save it all into a text file?

Comment: Please read the question again

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the same function for all `Entry` widgets?

Comment: Yes! One button should be able to retrieve what has been asked for in the question

Comment: Also, with the function. I'm guessing there should be an efficient way of doing it instead of manually inserting a .get() for every entry widget

Comment: I get that the first part and can solve that easily... but don't get the second one... what do you mean by "*there should be an efficient way of doing it instead of manually inserting a `.get()` for every entry widget*" ???

Comment: So in the function `get_entry()` that I have written, `EntryBox` is an Entry Widget. Like that, I have multiple Entry Widgets, like `EntryBoxa`, `EntryBoxb` and so on till n. Instead of adding a .get() for each and every Entry box **in** the function, there should be a way of pulling all the values together, which I'm guessing is what you have said you can solve easily

Comment: Also, I'd like to retrieve the text in the `Label` widget that is next to it as well, using the button and then save it all into .txt, as I have mentioned in the question

Comment: Judging by the use of the `get` function, it looks like you are using a `Text` widget, not an `Entry` widget. You should try to use the correct terminology in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of adding a `.get()` for each and every Entry box in the function, there should be a way of pulling all the values together

There isn't really. 
You have to use `.get()`, *but you don't have to do it by hand*.

When creating your window layout, save the labels and entry widget in a list of 2-tuples, like this;

```
mywidgets = [(Label1, Entry1), (Label2, Entry2), ...]
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
def get_entry():
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
        for label, entry in mywidgets:
            out.write(label['text']+entry.get()+'\n')
```

Comment: The idea works, however to retrieve Label values, you'll have to replace it with `label.cget("text")`

Comment: All configurable properties can be retrieved with dictionary-style access. See updated answer.